# How to display a COUNT query with group function

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to mySQL and as such am just looking for a very simple COUNT query which I haven't found explained online with any real clarity.

What I'm looking to do is to find how many teachers are belong to same country or location but at run time only name of counties display but not count of teacher i need output like

Name of city    count
india             3
USA               5
UK                2

my code is

```
<body>
<?php
include("connection.php");
?>
<table border="1px">
<tr>
<td>Country</td>
<td>'count( teachercode )</td>
</tr>
<?php
$query=mysql_query("SELECT Country, count(teachercode) from teacher group by Country") or die (mysql_error());
?>
<?php 
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {?>
 <tr>
    <td>
<a href="student.php?sr=<?php echo $row['sr'];?>">
<?php echo $row['Country']?></a> </td><td> <?php echo $row['count( teachercode )']?></td>
</tr>
<?php }
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

please help me

Comment: Use an alias. E.g. `SELECT count(teachercode) AS teachCodeCount` then access it in the array using the alias, e.g. `$row['teachCodeCount']`

Comment: tried but not working

Comment: What isn't working. Looking at your code, the `$row['sr']` bit won't, but the count example should work find as long as you don't have any types. It's pretty standard.

Answer (score 2):

Use an alias. E.g. `SELECT count(teachercode) AS teachCodeCount` then access it in the array using the alias, e.g. `$row['teachCodeCount']`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`SELECT Country, count(teachercode) as teachercount from teacher group by Country`

Comment: Dear Irfan first of all Thank you for your time butt it is working with Mysql only not displaying with script/ php at Clint end, i think i am making mistake with php